# Java JSON library supporting getting and setting deep values without schema?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jsonpath, lenses

I'm calling an API of some service and they return a gigantic JSON with literally around a hundred of fields and a dozen of nested objects. However, I don't need all of them. In fact, when doing GET or POST I really need from 3 to 7 fields. I very much want to avoid having this complex model in my application just to serialize/deserialize a couple of fields.

Essentially, I wanted to achieve:

1. Deserialize their gigantic **nested** JSON string to my **flat** POJO.
2. Work in my code with my flat POJO projection.
3. Serialize my flat POJO to their complex nested schema.

My solution so far was to rely on [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath):

1. Create a custom annotation for fields in my flat POJO, like:

`@JsonPathField("$.very.deeply.nested.field.value")
 private String theOnlyFieldIneed;`

2. Create a util method that uses reflection to produce a map of `<fieldName, JsonPath.readValue()>` which I give to Jackson objectMapper to produce my POJO. So deserialization to a flat POJO part works.
3. For serialization, however, things are worse, because JsonPath throws an exception if the path doesn't exist in the String. Like,

`// This will throw an exception:
DocumentContext document = JsonPath.using(jsonPathConfig).parse("{}");
document.set("$.not.even.deepest", value);`

4. To workaround that, I added kinda original schema as a string to feed to JsonParh.parse(Pojo.Prototype) but this is ugly, tedious and error-prone.

Basically, I'm looking for Immutable.JS kind of behaviour: [Collection.SetIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn)

Comment: I see there is already a feature request for JsonPath: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Kson (https://github.com/kantega/kson) which has a pretty straighforward support for extracting values from nested structures.

```
public class DecodeExample {

public static class Address {
    final String street;
    final String zip;

    public Address(String street, String zip) {
        this.street = street;
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}

static class User {
    final String                name;
    final Address address;

    User(String name, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JsonDecoder<Address> adressDecoder =
      obj(
        field("street", stringDecoder),
        field("zip", stringDecoder.ensure(z -> z.length() < 5)), //You can add constraints right here in the converter
        Address::new
      );


    JsonResult<JsonValue> json =
      JsonParser.parse(jsonString);

    Address address =
      json.field("model").field("leader").field("address").decode(adressDecoder).orThrow(RuntimeException::new);

    System.out.println(address);

    JsonResult<Address> userAddress =
      json.field("model").field("users").index(0).field("address").decode(adressDecoder);

    System.out.println(userAddress);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this example really cleared things up https://github.com/kantega/kson/blob/master/src/test/java/org/kantega/kson/example/DeepNestedDecoderExample.java